# ED.saveHTML is blocked when saving Wordpress pages

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

After implementing SSL and upgrading to 4.3 my Wordpress is unable to commit changes to the post or page status, visibility, or save any page meta - although anything in the main editor window can be updated nothing else changes.

Repairing the database and uploading a fresh copy of the wordpress core has not fixed the problem.

The only error I can see is in the javascript console. When the 'update' button is clicked `ED.saveHTML is blocked` and `editor.js?ver=4.3:428 ED.saveHTML is blocked`, this appears three times.

Comment: Do you have adblock plus or something similar that might be blocking things?

Comment: @Mike I do - but loading the site in an incognito window or alternate browser also produces these errors, and they are reported by other users. So I don't believe AdBlock to be the source of the issue.

Comment: Can you provide the actual url? It really seems to me like something is blocking it client side.

Comment: @Mike the url is integrityresearch[dot]com

Comment: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.yoursite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.eue27west.com/Track/Capture.aspx?retType=js&trk_user=47474&trk_s…tyresearch.com&trk_guid=0afe1b7c-2e70-4106-82a1-09dd27cb2b31&trk_cookie=NA'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Hmm I'm not thinking straight here. Is the only way to reproduce the error to modify a post? If so then I can't really do a whole lot.

Comment: @Mike - valid idea and I hadn't checked if a similar error was occurring outside of wordpress. The object that is being blocked is a tracking URL only - nothing to do with Wordpress.